# Is there a combined frequency argument in pd.date_range() function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date-range

How can I add only two days to my frequency? I would like to select Wednesdays and Mondays.
the code below only generates Wednesdays in my data.

```
pd.date_range(11/21/2019, periods=5, freq='W-WED')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `pd.date_range` supports combine frequency string as in your case. In your case, you need to construct 2 datetimeindexes and using `union` and slicing to get desired output

```
ix_mon = pd.date_range('11/21/2019', periods=5, freq='W-MON')
ix_wed = pd.date_range('11/21/2019', periods=5, freq='W-WED')
ix_mw = ix_mon.union(ix_wed)[:5]

Out[806]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-25', '2019-11-27', '2019-12-02', '2019-12-04',
               '2019-12-09'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: @TD1: because OP needs only first 5 elements of  `MON` and `WED`